# Does windowAll operator in Flink scale down the parallelization to 1?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

I have a stream in Flink which sends cubes from a source, make a transformation on the cube(adding 1 to each element in the cube), then lastly send it downstream to print the throughput of every second.

The stream is parallelized over 4 threads.

If I understand correctly the `windowAll` operator is a non-parallel transformation and should therefore scale down the parallelization back to 1, and by using it together with `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1))`, sum the throughput of all parallelized subtasks within the latest second and print it. I'm unsure if I get correct output since the throughput every second is printed like this:

```
1> 25
2> 226
3> 354
4> 372
1> 382
2> 403
3> 363
...
```

Question: Does the stream printer print the throughput from each thread(1,2,3 & 4), or is it only that it chooses e.g. thread 3 to print the throughput sum of all the subtasks on?

When I set the parallelism of the environment to 1 in the beginning`env.setParallelism(1)`, I don't get the "x> " before the throughput, but I seem to get the same(or even better) throughput as when it is set to 4. Like this:

```
45
429
499
505
1
503
524
530
...
```

Here is a code-snippet of the program:

```
imports...

public class StreamingCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int parallelism = 4;

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
                StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);
        env.setParallelism(parallelism);

        DataStream<Cube> start = env
                .addSource(new CubeSource());

        DataStream<Cube> adder = start
                .map(new MapFunction<Cube, Cube>() {
                    @Override
                    public Cube map(Cube cube) throws Exception {
                        return cube.cubeAdd(1);
                    }
                });

        DataStream<Integer> throughput = ((SingleOutputStreamOperator<Cube>) adder)
                .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
                .apply(new AllWindowFunction<Cube, Integer, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(TimeWindow tw,
                                      Iterable<Cube> values,
                                      Collector<Integer> out) throws Exception {
                        int sum = 0;
                        for (Cube c : values)
                            sum++;
                        out.collect(sum);
                    }
                });
        throughput.print();
        env.execute("Cube Stream of Sweetness");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the parallelism of the environment is set to 3 and you are using a WindowAll operator, only the window operator runs in parallelism 1. The sink will still be running with parallelism 3. Hence, the plan looks as follows:

```
In_1 -\               /- Out_1
In_2 --- WindowAll_1 --- Out_2
In_3 -/               \- Out_3
```

The WindowAll operator emits its output to its subsequent tasks using a round-robin strategy. That's the reason for the different threads emitting the result records of program.

When you set the environment parallelism to 1, all operators run with a single task.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!